# SQL if any in this range, true, else false

Tags: sql

So I am pulling back distinct account_ids based on one table, then joining in a second table to sum up all the invoices for said account.

EX: account_id: 1234567

Say there were 4 invoices associated with 1234567, I am summing the volumece of those 4 invoices and presenting that back.

NOW, I also want to loop through those 4 invoices and check if ANY of them fall within 90 days of my 'date' from the original table commitments.

Here is what i have, BUT it does not work because that is only grabbing the most recent invoice, whereas I need to loop through all of them to check if it is 'NEW' (NO invoices within 90 days) or 'RECURRING' (ANY one of those 4 invoices are within that 90 day window)

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT  
    MIN(c.created_at) AS date,
    c.meta_account_Id, 
    c.organization_Id, 
    c.user_id, 
    c.meta_distributorId, 
    c.meta_accountName,
    sum( CASE WHEN s.invoice_date>=c.created_at 
         THEN  coalesce(s.volumece,0)     
         ELSE 0
         END ) AS ces,
    CASE WHEN (max(s.invoice_date)) BETWEEN (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),-90)) AND (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),1)) 
         THEN 'RECURRING'
         ELSE 'NEW'
         END AS type

FROM [commitments] c

LEFT JOIN [Sales2] s ON c.organization_Id=s.org_id AND
                        c.meta_account_Id=s.account_id

WHERE 
      c.status='active' AND 
      c.organization_Id='57aa010ae6125c0b007d241c' AND 
      c.user_id='598de688834ff20518a536d9'


GROUP BY 
      c.meta_account_Id, 
      c.organization_Id, 
      c.user_id, 
      c.meta_distributorId, 
      c.meta_accountName
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using?  "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Ill be honest, not 100% sure. It is through a new BI tool that we purchase, so still learning.

Answer (score 0):

I take it instead of knowing if the MAX invoiceDate falls within 90 days, with this:

```
CASE
    WHEN (max(s.invoice_date)) BETWEEN 
(adddays(MIN(c.created_at),-90)) AND (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),1)) 
THEN 'RECURRING'
    ELSE 'NEW'
END AS type
```

You want to return "RECURRING" if ANY related invoiceDate falls within 90 days.   The way to do this (at least in all the flavors of SQL I know) is with an EXISTS() function:

```
CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sales2 t1
WHERE t1.invoice_date BETWEEN 
(adddays(MIN(c.created_at),-90)) AND (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),1)) 
AND c.organization_Id=t1.org_id AND 
    c.meta_account_Id=t1.account_id)
THEN 'RECURRING'
    ELSE 'NEW'
END AS type
```

Comment: Not too familiar with exists function... however, i tried to implement and am getting an error for too many nested operators

Comment: CASE
     WHEN EXISTS(SELECT t1.account_id, t1.org_id, t1.invoice_date
     FROM [Sales2] t1
     WHERE (t1.invoice_date BETWEEN (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),-90)) AND (adddays(MIN(c.created_at),1))) AND t1.org_id=c.organization_Id AND t1.account_id=c.     meta_account_Id)
  THEN 'RECURRING'
     ELSE 'NEW'
 END AS type